# Custom coordinate 2D Helmert transformation in QGIS to Sweref 99 20 15

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a local cartographic system in a shp file which translates to Sweref 992015, EPSG:3016 using a 2D Helmert translation. The coordinates are in the shp file x=7130.125, y=3060.129, s=0.9999555792 and theta=82284.8452 (a=0.9214369159 and b= -0.3884136588). Corresponding point in epsg3016 is x=7174622.121 and y=198905.500.

I tried using a proj string: `cct -z 0 +proj=helmert +convention=coordinate_frame +x=7130.125 +y=3060.129 +s=0.9999555792 +theta=82284.8452 <Helmertin.txt >>Helmertout.txt`

I am not sure if there is support still in QGIS 3.16.1 having Proj 6.3.2? But if so what have I done wrong in the proj string?